# Leafletjs - GeoJSON layer not showing

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I have created a jsfiddle of the code and I don't know why the marker is not showing.

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [8.99665, 38.81573],
    zoom: 13,
}); 

var addis = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        id: 'addis',
        attribution: '&copy; <a  href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
}).addTo(map);

var aa = {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "name": "Megenagna",
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [9.019720, 38.802933]
    }
};

new L.GeoJSON(aa).addTo(map);
```

Here is the jsfiddle url: http://jsfiddle.net/m2ju1m3v/

Please, can someone shine some light on this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Coordinates in GeoJSON are specified as an array of form `[longitude, latitude]`, on the contrary of Leaflet where it is `[latitude, longitude]`.

So you should simply change your coordinates to:

```js
"coordinates": [38.802933, 9.019720]
```

Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m2ju1m3v/2/

Note: please use Leaflet version 0.7.7 instead of 0.6.4.

Comment: Oh my! This has been driving me mad all morning. Thank you so much! This has answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the marker is added, but it is located just south of Sardina (Italy). That is because of GeosJON coordinates order: first `longitude`, second `latitude`.

Why do you use GeoJSON to add just a label? You can use just `marker` method to achieve it:

```
new L.marker([8.99665, 38.81573]).addTo(map);
```

Comment: I'm not just adding a marker, I just simplified the code for the sake of asking the question in a clear way... I'm actually developing a metro map application and I am trying to add all the stations via GeoJSON....